# 2 circuits in single Box for kitchen receptacle how to properly wire

Tags: gfci

I have an issue with 2 independent circuits in a single box. Is it possible to put a Gfci switch at this location one circuit is connected to my basement bathroom via the kitchen circuit the other wires are part where of another circuit with its own breaker for the counter top outlets.

It seems strange to have 2 circuits in one box there is a gfci upstream immediately after a refrigerator outlet that supports all the outlets on the kitchen counter. I don’t understand why there is 2 different circuit with a line coming from the other circuit where all the outlets work fine

I am concerned about protection for the bathroom in the basement

Comment: Are you seeking GFCI protection for a receptacle here? Or aiming to protect downline outlets?  How does the switch figure into it?

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the box involved?